# Meteor OAuth callback URL problems with Heroku domains

Tags: heroku, oauth, meteor

I have several Meteor apps hosted on Heroku. This usually has worked fine.

The last few I've set up, however, are having issues with the accounts-google OAuth package. What's supposed to happens is:

1. User visits www.foo.com/login and clicks "Sign in with Google"
2. Google authenticates and calls back to www.foo.com/_oauth/google?close
3. The popup closes and the user is now authenticated on www.foo.com.

Instead, at step 2, Google is calling back to foo.herokuapp.com/_oauth/google?close. The upshot is I can't log in at www.foo.com. I can go to foo.herokuapp.com/login and that works, but that obviously is only a short-term solution for admins and untenable for ordinary users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When meteor boots it uses a ROOT_URL env variable. If you set this to `foo.com` instead of `foo.herokuapp.com` it will no longer do this.

Meteor uses the `ROOT_URL` environment variable to determine where to redirect to with the oauth plugins